# UITableView didSelectRowAt is not called iOS 10, but works for 9.3.5

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios10

There are lots of questions regarding this problem, but the answers I have found so far are not applicable. In this case, the table works correctly in iOS 9.3.5, but not for iOS 10 (or 10.3.1)

I have ruled out:

- Not setting up the delegate properly. The delegate performs 3 functions, `didSelectRowAt`, `heightForRowAt`, and `editActionsForRowAt`. *The latter is the right-to-left swipe which gives the option to perform the exact same functionality as selecting the row.*. These three functions work correctly on v9.3.5 (as tested via simulator and and older iPad I test with.) When I use v10 via the simulator or my iPhone SE, the `heightForRowAt`, and `editActionsForRowAt` work but not the `didSelectRowAt` (and for that matter - I tried `willSelectRowAt`. It also did not work for v10.)
- Any typographical error (because it works for 9.3.5)

I have not been able to find anything about a Swift change regarding `tableView(:didSelectRowAt)` from iOS 9 to iOS 10.

**Background**

I have a view controller with a corresponding xib ("DetailVC"). This xib has a label then a tableview underneath the label. The table's cell is another xib.

The view controller presented via

```
let uomVC = DetailVC()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(uomVC, animated: true)
```

Then within DetailVC, I use a NSFetchedDataController and connect it to tableview via the tableView Data Source delegate. (Core data loads and displays great.)

**Code** (I'll post additional code as needed/ requested - Swift 3)

*viewDidLoad() - partial*

```
let nib: String = "DetailCell"
let reuseID: String = "detailCell"
tableView.register(UINib.init(nibName: nib, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseID)
```

*tableView(:cellForRowAt)*

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseID) as! IngredientDetailCell
    cell.present(ingredient: _fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath))
    cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true // Added later as a guess per SO suggestions
    return cell
}
```

For arguments sake - this won't print

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {      
    print("Selected a row")
    // delegate?.selectedIngredient(_fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath))
    // self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

**View**

[image: tableViewCell]

Comment: what are the contents of the cell? I mean since it's a custom cell, what is the view hierarchy of `cell.contentView`?

Comment: @Malik - There's a pair of labels within a horizontal stack

Comment: Make sure you're including your UITableViewDelegate and then self.tableView.delegate = self self.tableView.dataSource = self in viewDidLoad

Comment: Make sure you are not using any gesture. If you are using any gesture please just remove it and try didselectat method

Comment: Looks like an interesting case. Will have to look at the class where you are using the tableView and possibly the tableView attributes in storyboard.

Comment: Just to make it clear is it exactly the same code being run on iOS 9 and iOS 10?

Comment: Does `tableView` recognises other touches on iOS 10? Do other delegate methods get called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*For completeness in case anyone has this strange situation.*

The problem was my UITableViewCell xib. I must have originally designed it as a UIView, then added the UITableViewCell. The hierarchy should begin with the UITableViewCell. I moved the UITableViewCell out from underneath the view (circled in red), deleted the view and re-connected the IBOutlets. It's just strange that it worked with iOS 9.3.5.

[image]